# How are physical quantum chips made?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

So this might be a dumb question, but I have trouble finding any information on the physical aspect of quantum computers. 
Online you can find only pictures of big bulky things said to be quantum computers and searching for quantum circuits only results in descriptions of equations for quantum operations.

What I want to know is what is the quantum version of classical PCBs, are they also made on silicon wafers or is it a different material and method altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the architecture. Superconducting quantum  chips (currently the most popular architecture) are indeed fabricated on Silicon wafers. There's a nice schematic in [arXiv:1901.08042](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08042). 
[image]